# c# How can I map an Array object property to a Mongodb BsonType.Array

Tags: c#, arrays, database, mongodb, bson

I have the following object in my models:

```
[BsonId]
[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
public string Id { get; set; }

[BsonElement("Name")]
[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
public string Name { get; set; }

[BsonElement("Price")]
[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Double)]
public double Price { get; set; }

[BsonElement("Type")]
[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Array)]
public string[] Type { get; set; }
```

when I try to insert a new object to the database using =>

> MongoCollection.InsertOne(object);

the following error occurs

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'OrdisTT.Libs.MongoLib' threw an exception.
 ---> System.ArgumentException: GenericArguments[0], 'System.Array', on 'MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.EnumerableInterfaceImplementerSerializer`1[TValue]' violates the constraint of type 'TValue'.
 ---> System.TypeLoadException: GenericArguments[0], 'System.Array', on 'MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.EnumerableInterfaceImplementerSerializer`1[TValue]' violates the constraint of type parameter 'TValue'.
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.Instantiate(Type[] inst)
   at System.RuntimeType.MakeGenericType(Type[] instantiation)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

How can I map an array property to a mongodb array?

Comment: Can you check if the .NET side type is `List<string>` if it's working?

Comment: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/14e046f23640ff9257c4edf53065b9a6768254d4/tests/MongoDB.Bson.Tests/Serialization/Serializers/ArraySerializerTests.cs looks like arrays are represented as strings in the tests ([BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I just make the field or property like this:

```
public List<string> SomeList = new List<string>();
```

it will map, no need for representation.